# Next JS getServerSideProps try block failing when getting token in Vercel

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, next.js, getserversideprops

I am trying to hide one of my routes in NextJS behind firebase Auth. I am storing a token in the context and retrieving the token in getServerSideProps. This works in development but once deployed to Vercel it fails.
I see the cookie is there after logging in but the try block fails.

[image]

I'm wondering if it's a race condition in the production env but I am using async await.

Here is the bloc that is failing.

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    //console.log(context)
    try {        
        const cookies = nookies.get(context);
        //const cookies = Cookies.get(context);
        const token = await verifyIdToken(cookies.token);
        const {uid, email} = token;
        //console.log("Token in vendors: ", token);
        return {
            props: {
                session: `Email: ${email} IUD: ${uid}`
            }
        }
    } catch (err) {
        context.res.writeHead(302, {location: "/"}); //login //change to welcome page
        context.res.end();
        return (
            { props: [] }
        )
    }
}
```

I am using nookies and I even tries switching to cookie-js as someone suggested.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

here is the repo:
https://github.com/craigbauerwebdev/next-tartanbook

The token is set here:
https://github.com/craigbauerwebdev/next-tartanbook/blob/master/components/Auth/Auth.js

The Token is being retrieved here:
https://github.com/craigbauerwebdev/next-tartanbook/blob/master/pages/vendors/index.js

Comment: So the token verification fails?

Comment: Yeah. And the try catch goes to catch and kicks back to the home page even though I see the token in the cookies.